# Как реализовать обработку http запросов get/post/put/delete с использованием com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer?

Tags: java, http

Есть простой Http Server

```
private com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer server = null;
    public void startHttpServer(int port) {
            try {
                server = com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("HTTP server started at " + port);
            server.createContext("/", new RootHandler());
            server.createContext("/api/0.1/device_configuration", new PostDeviceConfiguration());
            server.createContext("/api/0.1/order", new PutCancellationOrder());
            server.createContext("/api/0.1/order", new PostOrder());

            server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
            server.start();
        }
```

Может ли такой сервер различать различать http методы get/post/rest/delete ? Если да, то как это сделать? Необходимо реализовать post и put с одинаковым URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно определить какой используется метод через [`HttpExchange.getRequestMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#getRequestMethod())

---

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class TestHttpServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/", http -> {
            String response = createResponse(http.getRequestMethod().toUpperCase());
            http.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Type", "text/html");
            http.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = http.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        });
        server.setExecutor(null); 
        server.start();
        System.out.println("http://localhost:8080/");
    }

    private static String createResponse(String requestMethod) {
        String resp = "<svg viewbox='-10 -10 20 20' height='100vh'><text text-" +
           "anchor='middle' stroke='red' stroke-width='0.05' font-size='4'>%s</text></svg>";
        if ("GET".equals(requestMethod)) 
            return String.format(resp, "GET");
        if ("POST".equals(requestMethod)) 
            return String.format(resp, "POST");
        return "unknown method";
    }
}
```