# Java HTTP сервер

Tags: java

Никак не могу сделать HTTP сервер на Java. Мне нужно чтобы сервер мог слушать порт и разные пути, например:

`localhost:4040/test`

`localhost:4040/send`

`localhost:4040/a/b/c`

Чтобы я мог обрабатывать как GET так и POST запросы.
И как получить русские символы из InputStream в котором храниться тело POST запроса
И также сервер должен быть многопоточный. Я нахожу только что-то одно в решениях, только многопоточность, только GET запросы. Можно пример кодом, или репозиторием, как все это сделать?

Comment: смотрите [micronoaut](https://habr.com/ru/post/418117/) или [springboot](https://habr.com/ru/post/435144/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разбейте свою задачу на несколько более мелких. И решайте их постепенно.
Вначале создайте веб сервер, который сможет хоть как то ответить hello-world. Посмотрите пример здесь, например - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api  или здесь [Как реализовать обработку http запросов get/post/put/delete с использованием com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993928/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-http-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-get-post-put-delete-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-com)

Там есть как возможность использовать встроенный, так и различные сторонние библиотеки.

> И как получить русские символы из InputStream в котором храниться тело POST запроса

А здесь у Вас сломано понимание. Нет никаких особых русских символов. Есть байты (то, как оно хранится) и кодировки - правила, которые преобразовывают эти байты в символы и шрифты, которые их уже отрисовывают (грубо конечно, но думаю, будет чуточку понятнее). А вот понятны ли они пользователю будут - это совсем другой вопрос. Если отправляющая сторона корректно закодирует, а принимающая корректно раскодирует, то все будет работать. Если сомневаетесь, используйте везде utf-8. А InputStream  в принципе абсолютно побоку, какие байтики передавать. То есть, если в файл можете сохранить, что бы потом в текстовом редакторе открыть и оно работает, то все будут работать.

> И также сервер должен быть многопоточный

для начинающих  это абсолютно не важно. Сервер может и на одном потоке аккуратно разруливать все Ваши запросы.